# How to SUM up first word in a string from text file based on distinct occurrence

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have this shell script running every 1 minute via cronjob, and the output will store in `result.txt`:

## CODE 1 - shell script `check.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
netstat -anp |grep 'SYN' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '{$1=$1;print}' > result.txt
```

Here is the output of `result.txt`, where the number 1, 2 and 4 on the left side are from the total how many time an IP make SYN_FLOOD request:

```
1 73.207.15.237
2 73.229.249.226
4 137.74.155.171
```

So, to display the output on my website, I have the following PHP script file called `index.php` that reads this `result.txt` and display it when someone goes to url/index.php

## CODE 2 - PHP script `index.php`

```
$file = 'result.txt';
$count = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($ip_raw = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $count++;
    $syn_count = explode(' ',trim($ip_raw))[0];
    $ip = substr($ip_raw, 2);
    echo "<div>{$count}) <font color='orange'>[ $syn_count ]{$ip}</font> [ <a 
    href='https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/{$ip}' target='_blank'>info</a> ]</div>";
}
    if($count==0)
            echo "<div> <font color='orange'>No IP with SYN_RECV status at this moment</font></div>";

fclose($handle);
} else {
echo "<div>[maxidos | info]: <font color='red'>Error opening ip data</font></div>";
}
```

The output for this `index.php` is:

```
1) [ 1 ] 73.207.15.237 [ info ]
2) [ 2 ] 73.229.249.226 [ info ]
3) [ 4 ] 137.74.155.171 [ info ]
```

When the shell script run again from `CODE 1`, I might get different output in `result.txt` based on how many time the IP make SYN request. Example the new `result.txt` I will get like this:

```
4 73.207.15.237
1 77.129.349.226
2 133.74.155.171
```

Based on the new `result.txt` output above, you can see that only the first IP `73.207.15.237` has a previous history of doing syn request which was 1 time and the other 2 IPs are new. My question is, how do I sum up the total SYN request made by IP `73.207.15.237` which has a previous history of making SYN request of 1 time + 4 (current). The output that I want on the website including the new 2 IPs should be:

```
1) [ 5 ] 73.207.15.237 [ info ]  -- has history of SYN count=1 and current SYN=4. So total SYN count, 1+4=5
2) [ 2 ] 73.229.249.226 [ info ] -- has history of SYN count but no current SYN count found in result.txt, so no sum is done here
3) [ 4 ] 137.74.155.171 [ info ] -- has history of SYN count but no current SYN count found in result.txt, so no sum is done here
4) [ 1 ] 77.129.349.226 [ info ] -- new IP
5) [ 2 ] 133.74.155.171 [ info ] -- new IP
```

So when the shell script keep running and if found the same IP making the same request, it should update the total SYN request on the left side. I'm not sure if I need to implement this via shell or PHP.

Maybe my brief question for this long post would be:

How do I SUM up the first word from a string with multi-line in `result.txt` based on distinct occurrence?

## Edit 1 (My idea):

My idea, the output from `result.txt` will be stored in a new txt file called result_final.txt, then when the new result came from `result.txt`, we compare both `result.txt` and `result_final.txt`. So the website will only read `result_final.txt`. But how do I make this comparison? I started to think that I need some kind of algorithm to make this comparison, or is there a simpler way of implementing this in shell script or bash?

## Edit 2 (about the given answer):

Based on the solution given by @ChrisBrownie55,

I made changes to `CODE 1` that output the `result.txt`:

```
#!/bin/sh
netstat -anpt | awk '/SYN/{split($5,a,":");seen[a[1]]++}END{for(i in seen){print seen[i],i}}' | sed -e "s/ /:/g" > result.txt
```

and it will produce output for `result.txt` like below:

```
1:174.137.58.23
2:71.14.74.120
1:51.36.113.39
```

So, in order not to disturb my `CODE 1`, I created another script that will produce `result_final.txt`. This file is used to store the count:

So the code for producing the `result_final.txt` is based on answer from @ChrisBrownie55 with a little bit change on the output:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 file="result.txt"
 file2="result_final.txt"
 if [[ ! -f "$file2" || ! -s "$file2" ]]; then
    echo "file2 not exist or empty. init"
    cat $file > $file2
 fi
# get all results in "<count>:<ip>" format
entries=`cat $file $file2 | tr ' ' ':'`
results=""

for entry in $entries; do
  # separate the count and ip address
  count=${entry/:*/}
  ip=${entry/*:/}

  # check for an existing result
  result=`echo $results | grep -F "$ip"`
  if [[ $result ]]; then
    # if one was found, extract its count
    currentCount=${result/:*/}
    totalCount=$(( currentCount + count )) # add em up

    # replace the old result entry with the new one
    results=${results/$currentCount:$ip/$totalCount:$ip}
  else
    # if no result exists, create one
    results="$results$count:$ip\n"
   fi
done

# print results in "<count> <ip>" format
echo -e "$results" | tr ':' ' ' | sed -e "s/ /:/g" | grep "\S" | sort -nr > $file2
```

The above script will produce the following output for `result_final.txt`:

```
1:174.137.58.23
2:71.14.74.120
1:51.36.113.39
```

## Edit 3: SOLVED Thank you so much @ChrisBrownie55

I thought I was having problem with the output, but I notice it was my mistake because I had this running on cronjob:

```
0 * * * *       root  cat /dev/null > /root/result_final.txt

I changed it to clear the result every 12AM:

0 0 * * *       root  cat /dev/null > /root/result_final.txt
```

The solution given by @ChrisBrownie55 works.

Comment: Btw.: `sh` != `bash`

Comment: updated. sorry for that.

Comment: FYI, you're entire pipeline that makes `result.txt` can be reduced to a single call to [tag:awk] like so `netstat -anpt | awk '/SYN/{split($5,a,":");seen[a[1]]++}END{for(i in seen){print seen[i],i}}' > result.txt`

Comment: I'd strongly consider using a database instead of a text file to store your results, with timestamps so you can display the most recent data set, or cumulative totals as far back as you want.

Comment: @SiegeX thanks for the single line call. Shawn: Good idea to use the database but unfortunately I'm not planning to use database for various reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I changed the answer because the old way of finding and replacing was overly complex, associative arrays make the code much simpler.

## Associative Arrays

To add up all the counts, we will iterate over all of the lines inside of each file with a read-while loop. With each line, you can extract both the `count` and the `ip`.

Once we have our values for that line, we can check our associative array, `results`, for an existing entry.

- if one is found: add the `count` to the existing count
- otherwise: create an entry with `count`

Once that's all said and done, we can now print out the `results` associative array. To do this, we will iterate over the *keys* inside `results` with the `${!var[*]}` syntax.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A results

while read entry; do
  # separate the count and ip address
  count=${entry/:*/}
  ip=${entry/*:/}

  # check for an existing result
  if [[ ${results[$ip]} ]]; then
    # add the count to existing entry
    results[$ip]=$(( ${results[$ip]} + count ))
  else
    # if no result exists, create one
    results[$ip]=$count
  fi
done < <(cat result.txt result2.txt)

# print results in "<count>:<ip>" format
for ip in ${!results[*]}; do
  echo ${results[$ip]}:$ip
done
```

---

#### What the heck is `done < <(cat result.txt result2.txt)`?

It is the combination of a [read-while loop](http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/loops/) taking input from a file and [process substitution](https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh) which allows us to use commands as inputs where we can't use the pipe operator `|`.

See also [associative arrays](https://fabianlee.org/2020/02/15/bash-associative-array-initialization-and-usage/).

## Shorter Option: `awk` + associative arrays

The `awk` command also supports associative arrays in its code. We can leverage this to quickly handle the two fields (`count` and `ip`) and convert them to an associative array and print them out easily.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=":"
  OFS=":"
}

{
  ips[$2]+=$1
}

END {
  for (ip in ips)
    print ips[ip], ip
}
```

#### `BEGIN` Block

In this code, we start by defining the `FS` (field separator) and the `OFS` (output field separator). These allow us to configure `awk` to look split each line to fields by the `:` and, when we print them out, to put them back together with `:`.

#### Main Code Block

In `awk`, we don't need to declare our associative array or any initial values. We are able to access them right away and add to them as we did above.

With this, we are saying take the second field `$2` (our IP address) and use it as the key for `ips`. Then, we'll add the value held in the first field `$1` (the count) to it.

#### `END` Block

Here we're iterating over the keys in the associative array. With each key, we will print out the value at that key in the associative array and then the key itself. Each field is separated by the `OFS`.

### Pipeline version

If you wish to avoid making new files, you can also use the pipeline version of this (aka one-liner).

```sh
<command> | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"; OFS=":"} {ips[$2]+=$1} END {for (ip in ips) print ips[ip], ip}'
```

Comment: Something wrong with the output if the total number on the left has more than 1 character. For example. This is ok `4:73.207.15.237` but this is not ok `14:73.207.15.237` (the count has more than 2 characters). I'm checking right now.

Comment: Works fine when I run it.. What was the error or output that happened?

Comment: Ok sorry I monitored this weird behavior incorrectly. It was because I created a cronjob each minute to clear the result. Thank you so much for the solution!